# how to align column value into a string based on its value in Python

Tags: python

I have this column in df I would like to realign to specific format with a fixed max width of 7, it is basically a weekday number, so only 1-7 is coded in the input table. Help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

INPUT TABLE:

| colA |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 7 |
| 456 |
| 1234567 |

DESIRED OUTPUT TABLE

| colA |
| --- |
| 123^^^^ |
| ^^^^^^7 |
| ^^^456^ |
| 1234567 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: the data doesn't have 931, it is basically a weekday number

Comment: Could there be an empty item, ie. no number at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [123, 7, 456, 1234567]})

def func(x):
    xs = str(x)
    z= ''
    for i,j in enumerate('^^^^^^^'):
        if str(i+1) in xs:
            res = str(i+1)
        else:
            res = j
        z = z+res
    return z

df['colA'] = df['colA'].map(func)

print(df)
```

gives:

```
      colA
0  123^^^^
1  ^^^^^^7
2  ^^^456^
3  1234567
```

Comment: In response to @Timus, the code above gives '^^^^^^^' for None ('ie empty DF cell)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a function to output those rows?

```py
def pad_days(days_as_str: str) -> str:
    assert all(c.isdigit() for c in days_as_str), f"unknown characters in {days_as_str}"
    week = "^" * 7
    for day_str in days_as_str:
        d = int(day_str)
        assert 0 < d < 8, f"invalid digit {day_str}"
        week = week[:d-1] + day_str + week[d:]
    return week
```

```py
In [1]: def pad_days(days_as_str: str) -> str:
   ...:     assert all(c.isdigit() for c in days_as_str), f"unknown characters in {days_as_str}"
   ...:     week = "^" * 7
   ...:     for day_str in days_as_str:
   ...:         d = int(day_str)
   ...:         assert 0 < d < 8, f"invalid digit {day_str}"
   ...:         week = week[:d-1] + day_str + week[d:]
   ...:     return week
   ...: 

In [2]: pad_days("1237")
Out[2]: '123^^^7'

In [3]: pad_days("367")
Out[3]: '^^3^^67'
```

Now I don't find this function to be particularly idiomatic to Python. It's a good v0 to get started because it's explicit but it can certainly be optimized. As @sjshuck recommended, look into alternatives!

Comment: This is great, I was working on another version as well, very similar concept
input = [1, 3, 4]
def DOO_pad(input):
    output = ''
    ref = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for list in ref:
        if not list in input:
            char = '^'
        else:
            char = str(list)
        output= output + char
    return output


print(DOO_pad(input))

Answer (score 0):

I would loop over every possible slot in the output

```py
range(1, 7 + 1)
```

and turn each into a string using `str()`.  Then, for each, ask if it exists in the input

```py
s in input_cell
```

and emit a string that's either the number itself or the placeholder

```py
s if exists else '^'
```

and join them all

```py
''.join(results)
```

My style would be to use mostly functional idioms, using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), etc., but you can do this in traditional loops as well.

Note that this is technically has *O(NM)* complexity, but scanning tiny strings for characters will not cross cache line boundaries so it doesn't matter.  If the problem were days of the year rather than days of the week, a better algorithm might be called for.